# Jekyll conditional image tags are still showing up when not there

Tags: image, conditional-statements, jekyll, broken-links

i am using Jekyll for my site and i have conditional additional images that begin with {% if page.second-image %} and end with {% endif %} . unfortunately those image tags are still showing up even when there is no second image in the post. how do i get Jekyll to ignore them if they aren't coded into the current post? thanks!!

```
layout: post
title: title
date: 2015-09-02
image: /img/path.png
second-image: /img/path.png
third-image: /img/path.png
description: Landing Page/Menu Design
meta-title: meta title information
```

but the 4th, 5th and 6th images from the post template are showing as broken links even though theyre not there

Comment: Would you please add your posts yaml front-matter to your question?

Comment: sure. ---
layout: post
title: title
date: 2015-09-02
image: /img/path.png
second-image: /img/path.png
third-image: /img/path.png
description: Landing Page/Menu Design
meta-title: meta title information
--- but then the 4th, 5th and 6th images are showing as broken links even tho they arent in the post

Answer (score 1):

Alright, try this:

```
---
title: "My title" # wrap in double quotes
image: path.png # remove source folder
second-image: path.png
description: "My description" # wrap in double quotes
meta-title: "meta title information" # wrap in double quotes
... # whatever you need
---
```

Then, to `post.html` (or another html file where you calling the posts from):

```
{% if page.second-image %} <img class="some_class" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/img/{{ page.second-image }}" alt="{{ page.title }}"> {% endif %}
```

---

### OR:

```
---
extra_imgs: [path1.png, path2.png, path3.png]
---
```

then

```
{% if page.extra_imgs %} 
{% for img in page.extra_imgs %}
<img class="some_class" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/img/{{ img }}" alt="{{ page.title }}"> 
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

*Tip: avoid using special chars in the yaml frontmatter values. They can break the code after them! Anyway, if [using double quotes](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/763#issuecomment-12338454) you should be ok.*

Let me know how it goes!

Hope to have helped!

Comment: second option worked great!! thanks!!! so what was it i did wrong in my original file (just for learning purposes)?

Comment: Great! I'm not sure... Probably adding a ` / ` to yml values broke the rest of your code... If you may, would you upvote the answer and/or mark it as correct? By doing this you'll help me to increase my reputation! ;)

Comment: Perhaps you could try `second_image`  instead of `second-image` and check if works...